# Synchronize email accounts

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I'd Like to synchronize 2 email accounts. One empty and one with a bunch of emails. How do I do this without any loss? I know thunderbird lets you MOVE emails but it won't let you COPY them, IF I understood correctly?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you can copy your entire mail folder which is named like hb267c4l.default or similar. Ok I think i get it- you have 2 accounts within the same folder and you want to copy from one to another?

Comment: I host a mailserver and have an account on a closed environment rented server, I want to copy a whole account from the rentalserver to my own server.